# Arbitrary joins in XPath

Tags: xml, xpath

Is there a way to set a variable or otherwise remember a parent element so that *both* of its children can be matched against *both* of the children of another element?

**Example:**

```
<root> 
  <mybonds> 
    <bond> 
      <type>sellable</type>  
      <amount>100</amount> 
    </bond>  
    <bond> 
      <type>revocable</type>  
      <amount>5</amount> 
    </bond> 
  </mybonds>  
  <auctions> 
    <bond> 
      <type>sellable</type>  
      <amount>1</amount> 
    </bond>  
    <bond> 
      <type>revocable</type>  
      <amount>100</amount> 
    </bond> 
    <bond> 
      <type>sellable</type>  
      <amount>100</amount> 
    </bond> 
  </auctions> 
</root>
```

I want to check if `mybonds` `bound` elements are present in `auctions` `bonds`: That is, each `bond` must match exactly by `type` and `amount`.  But if I try to use this XPath expression

```
/root/mybonds/bond[type = /root/auctions/bond/type and amount = /root/auctions/bond/amount]
```

it selects the first `bond` because it matches against ***two different auctions bonds*** that separately have matching `type` and `amounts` instead of matching nothing because there is no *single* bond that matches *both* `type` and `amount`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### XPath 1.0

Cannot be done in XPath alone.

### XPath 2.0

```
for $b in /root/mybonds/bond 
    return if(/root/auctions/bond[type = $b/type and amount = $b/amount])
               then $b
               else ()
```